# Super Fan Rebus!

Tags: wordplay, rebus

This is a rebus I have made. I will accept partial answers, and I want to know the common theme. Some describe what something looks like, how it is spelled, and characteristics of that object. Enjoy :D

[image]

[image]

Inspiration from [Mic Crozier](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45816/mic-crozier)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Full Answer**
<sup>Don't forget to go upvote [@thecoder16's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61716) also!</sup>

1

> Ron   (R [Arrrrr!] + ON)

2

> Dumbledore (DUMB + BULL + D + ORE)

3

> Hagrid  (HA [HA] + Grid)

4

> Hermione (HER + MI + ONE)  (Got independently, but @thecoder16 posted first)

5

> Neville (Ne + Ville)  from @thecoder16

6

> Snape  (Tin=SN + SHAPE - SH)  from @thecoder16

7

> Minerva McGonagall (the witch who turns into a cat)

8

> Percy  (PURSE + E)

9

> Harry's owl Hedwig (HEAD + WIG)

10

> James [Potter]  (JAM + ESPURR - PURR)  (Got independently, but @thecoder16 posted first)

11

> Dudley  (DUD + FLY - F)  from @thecoder16

12

> Harry Potter

13

> Neville's toad Trevor (TREE + HERBIVORE - HERBIE)

And the theme is, of course,

> Harry Potter characters

Comment: It’s a miracle we haven’t sniped each other yet xD

Comment: @thecoder16 Well played.  *\*hat tip\**

Comment: You are right with Dumbledore, it was supposed to be **dumb + the cast of Bull + d + ore(From Settlers of Catan)**

Comment: Darn, sniped on 9 and yours definitely fits better. :P

Comment: Annnnd we got em all! :)

Comment: LOL after only, 20 minutes, and 9 views, all of them are solved. Great job guys :D

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer, will add more as I get them

4

> Her +mi+one =Hermione

5

> Ne + Vile = Neville?

6

> Sn(Tin)+Shape-Sh = Snape

10

> Jam + espurr-purr = James

11

> Dud + Fly-F= Dudl(e)y

Theme is probably

> Harry Potter

Comment: We almost collided on 10 just now.  Nice job :)